# Is there a way to have the first 6 rows of a dataset go to there own columns and then the 7th row go back to the first column

Tags: python, pandas, ocr

How can I assign rows to columns where the 1st-6th columns are rows 1-6 and the 7th row is loops back to the first column?

Comment: Can you provide some mock data with expected output?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose we have this data:

```
data = pd.Series(range(1,8))
```

Let's assume that these are repeated readings of six sensors, but we are not sure that the measurement cycle is completed. In case of `data` the cycle has been stopped at the first sensor in the second loop.

Now we want to arrange them in a table with data from each sensor in its own column. I can see two ways to do this. We could use `numpy.reshape` or `DataFrame.pivot`.

Here's the first way:

```
# append enough values to reshape the data
pad = [np.nan]*(6-len(data)%6)
values = np.r_[data.values, pad]

df = pd.DataFrame(values.reshape(-1, 6), columns=[*'123456'])
```

We might use here `numpy.concatenate` or `pandas.concat` as an alternative to `numpy.r_`. We can't use `numpy.resize` or `ndarray.resize` because of how they fill new cells.

Here's the second way I can think of. We create marks of rows and columns of the future table and then build a pivot relying on them:

```
df = data.to_frame()

df['my_rows'] = df.index // 6
df['my_columns'] = df.index % 6

df.pivot('my_rows', 'my_columns')
```

Here we could additionaly apply `df.reset_index(drop=True)` if the original index isn't a sequence `0,1,2,...` or we could use `pd.RangeIndex(len(df))` instead of `df.index` in further calculations. Anyway, I hope the main idea is clear enough.